# Copy and pasting rows based on a specific value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

So I have the following code which copies and pastes cells based on the input from a combobox, and I was wondering how I can adjust it to copy the whole rows rather than just the cells:

```
Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
K = 1
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("RAW Data")
Set w2 = Sheets("Output")
w1.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(Range("D5:D1048576"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, ModelSelection.Value) > 0 Then
        r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
```

To:

```
r.EntireRow.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
```

Entire code without `Activate` of the `w1` worksheet:

```
With w1
    For Each r In Intersect(.Range("D5:D1048576"), .UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, ModelSelection.Value) > 0 Then
            r.EntireRow.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End With
```

---

**Note**: a faster way would be not to **Copy >> Paste** so many times, but use a `CopyRng` object, which will save all merged `r` where the criteria is met, and then at the end just copy >> paste once (also don't need to advance `K`).

***Modified Code***

```
Dim CopyRng As Range

With w1
    For Each r In Intersect(.Range("D5:D1048576"), .UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(v, ModelSelection.Value) > 0 Then
            If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(r, CopyRng)
            Else
                Set CopyRng = r
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End With

' Copy >> Paste only once of the entire range
If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy w2.Cells(1, 1)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. How would I go about defining the output to start at a specific cell, e.g. paste the contents from cell c3?

Comment: @AaronGretton change `w2.Cells(1, 1)` to `w2.Range("C3")`

Comment: Cheers, using your modified code though I get the error "403 object required"

Comment: @AaronGretton at what line ?

Comment: Going back to the original code a second, I've tried to add a title row and copy and paste that along with the rest of the data:

`Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant, title As String, titlerow As Integer
    K = 1
    Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("RAW Data")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Output")
    w1.Activate
    title = "A4:AO4"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row`

Comment: To answer your question though its at the line `For Each r In Intersect(.Range("D5:D1048576"), .UsedRange)`

Answer (score 0):

you could also use `AutoFilter()`:

```
With Sheets("RAW Data")
    With .Range("D4", .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & Me.ModelSelection.Value & "*"
        With .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, .Columns.count).Offset(1, 0)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Copy Sheets("Output").Cells(1, 1)
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: This is actually faster, although theres >20k items in the list - will they all be picked up by this method?

Comment: well, just try it!

Comment: Also is there a way of specifying the location of the output (e.g. cell d2)

Comment: yes, just change `.Cells(1, 1)` to whatever location you need. If my answer solves your question you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you.

Comment: Thing is, as I'm copying rows it doesn't allow me to change the output as the areas "aren't the same size"

Comment: with my code you're not copying "rows" but "ranges". Has your "Output" sheet some merged cells?

Comment: maybe you're specifying the output location as a range: well, don't! you only have to specify it as the upper-left cell where to start pasting values from